# why my icon don't change when i'm clicking on ? (ionic/vue/ts)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3

Hi i'm trying to change my icon when i click on it but it doesn't work i dont know why ..
here is my template:

```
         <button>
          <ion-icon class="marge-image" :icon="onChange ? heart : heartOutline" @click="onChange = !onChange"></ion-icon>
        </button>
```

here is my script when i put onChange boolean on false and when I imported my icons (I tested them and they display well except when I click on my icon so that the animation changes) :

```
import { heart, heartOutline } from "ionicons/icons";

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    // IonButton,
    IonLabel,
    IonAvatar,
    //IonThumbnail,
    // IonList,
    // AnswerAverage,
    IonGrid,
    IonIcon,
    IonCol,
    IonRow,
  },
  setup() { 
    return { displayDate , heart, heartOutline, onChange: false };
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `onChange` as a literal `false`, which is not reactive.

Wrap the value in a a [`ref`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref) to enable reactivity:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      //onChange: false ❌ not reactive

      onChange: ref(false) ✅
    }
  }
}
```